# Drupal 6: custom admin login page

Tags: forms, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6, administration

I need to create a custom admin login page. What is the candidate tpl file?

Appreciate helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This walkthrough helped me a lot.

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/hacking-phptemplate

There is a section there pertaining to the login screen. I've used this method quite often.

Comment: This walkthrough is for Drupal 4.7. Even if the bases are the same for Drupal 5 and Drupal 6, simple copy/paste will not work.

Comment: It will work but not a straight copy and paste. This article is more updated. http://drupal.org/node/19855